# Knockout options bindings not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Ok I am probably doing something very silly that is preventing me from getting this to work, but here goes anyway:

I am trying to learn how to work with knockout and am trying to build a select list with options defined as an observable array. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./knockout-3.0.0.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var viewModel = {
                availableQuestions : ko.observableArray(['Who?', 'What?', 'When?']) 
            };

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        </script>
        <p>Questions to Ask: <select data-bind="options: availableQuestions"></select></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is basically right out of one of their own examples but I cannot get it to work. The select list is not populated at all. I am using the latest version of Chrome (31.0.1650.57) and have looked in developer tools to see if there are issues. I have confirmed that everything is loading properly (ie: knockout is loading, the html is valid) still nothing. Am I missing something obvious?

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/janarde/r9pCK/

**EDIT**

Thanks to PW Kad It turned out to be that the DOM wasn't loaded before the binding:

**EDIT**
Thanks to Ek0nomik for pointing out the need to put knockout stuff after the markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./knockout-3.0.0.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <p>Questions to Ask: <select data-bind="options: availableQuestions"></select></p>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var viewModel = {
                availableQuestions : ko.observableArray(['Who?', 'What?', 'When?']) 
            };

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put up fiddle for it?

Comment: Added the fiddle. Works there, but not in the browser.

Comment: What is not working? In which browser not working?

Comment: the select list drop down is not binding to the observableArray when viewed in chrome. I am testing this out and loading it from a file to view it. Knockout is loading according to chrome dev tools, but I wonder if it is a path issue to the library.

Comment: i am sure its path issue. I am sure you will be getting some error in console. can you check console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the DOM is loaded before you are trying to apply bindings?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./knockout-3.0.0.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Questions to Ask: <select data-bind="options: availableQuestions"></select></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var viewModel = {
                availableQuestions : ko.observableArray(['Who?', 'What?', 'When?']) 
            };

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was it. I just had to make sure that the document was ready.

Comment: The `ready` code in this post is not needed.  You just need to move the script below the markup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you call `applyBindings`.  Here is a working jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/b4wHQ/

**HTML**

```
<p>Questions to Ask: <select data-bind="options: availableQuestions"></select></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = {
    availableQuestions : ko.observableArray(['Who?', 'What?', 'When?']) 
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the binding was just missing from the example. I still have the issue in the browser despite the binding. It's almost as if the binding isn't working in the browser for some reason but I don't see how that is possible.